# Eclipse cannot find shell script in Post-build step

Tags: eclipse, shell

I have a shell script that should be running after the build step. I can run the shell in terminal from the Release directory but when I add it to eclipse it complains that "No such file or directory". What makes it confusing is that the same script works in the post-build of another project within eclipse!

I'm not sure if this affects anything, but the file is a soft link. It works in the terminal and for another project, so I don't think this should be the problem.

Things I have checked:

1. The shell script is in the correct directory.
2. The address of the shell script is correct.
3. The script file is executable.
4. Line endings are linux style.

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.4, Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was a very stupid bug but in the off chance that someone else might be haunted by it here is what happened:

I had a sample project that I used as a reference. So I just copied the post-build command from the other project to macOS notes, edited it, and put it in my project. Little I knew that macOS note just likes to change the characters! So a " was changed to “ which threw the whole thing off!